# Column spacing issue in printing the formatted output

Tags: java, console, spacing

So this is a snippet of my code that I need formatted:

```
double textbookprice = 0, tradebookprice = 0;
for(int i=0;i<tempTextbooks.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(tempTextbooks.get(i).dataMember +"\t "+tempTextbooks.get(i).title +"\t "+tempTextbooks.get(i).author+"\t $"+df.format(tempTextbooks.get(i).getPrice()));
    textbookprice = textbookprice + tempTextbooks.get(i).getPrice();
}
```

This is what I'm getting as output,

```
COS221   Introduction to Programming with C++    Y. Daniel Liang     $120.99
COS225   Java Foundations    John Lewis  $94.59
BUS398   Excel 2010 Power Programming with VBA   John Walkenbach     $87.99
```

I need the class numbers/Title/Author/Price to all have their own column

Comment: What do you mean have their own columns they all do as is? Do you mean all the columns be aligned?

Comment: Yeah i need each column to be aligned. 
So they would go |Class#|Title|Author|Price

Comment: Well you're going to want to calculate the max length for each column then pad every other value in the column with spaces to reach that length.

Comment: This is a good answer.  You should edit your title and add words like "print" and "align" so people can find this later.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [System.out.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to define the lengths of the field. Something like this

```
System.out.format("%-10s %-40s %-20s %-15s \n", tempTextbooks.get(i).dataMember, tempTextbooks.get(i).title, tempTextbooks.get(i).author, df.format(tempTextbooks.get(i).getPrice()));
```

This fixes the fidth of the first four columns to 10, 40, 20 and 15 characters. The `-` before them indicates that you want them left align. (You can drop `-` if you want right aligned table.)

You can change them as per your requirements.

**EDIT**

I've tried to reproduce this problem using this code

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s1 = {"COS221", "COS225", "BUS398"};
        String[] s2 = {"Introduction to Programming with C++", "Java Foundations", "Excel 2010 Power Programming with VBA"};
        String[] s3 = {"Y. Daniel Liang", "John Lewis", "John Walkenbach"};
        String[] s4 = {"$120.99", "$94.59", "$87.99"};

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.format("%-10s %-40s %-20s %-15s \n", s1[i], s2[i], s3[i], s4[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And output looks like this:

```
COS221     Introduction to Programming with C++     Y. Daniel Liang      $120.99         
COS225     Java Foundations                         John Lewis           $94.59          
BUS398     Excel 2010 Power Programming with VBA    John Walkenbach      $87.99
```

Comment: How do i get a "$" in front of the price now, i fixed it so its aligned now. but the $ is no longer there for price

Comment: the new line of code i used is System.out.format("%-10s %-40s %-20s %-15s \n", tempTextbooks.get(i).dataMember, tempTextbooks.get(i).title, tempTextbooks.get(i).author, df.format(tempTextbooks.get(i).getPrice()));

Comment: I don't think this new code should tamper with `$`. Have you checked for any errors? FYI, you can also place dollar before your last parameter `$%-15` like this `System.out.format("%-10s %-40s %-20s $%-15s \n", tempTextbooks.get(i).dataMember, tempTextbooks.get(i).title, tempTextbooks.get(i).author, df.format(tempTextbooks.get(i).getPrice()));`

Comment: Thanks for the help :)